# n-qubit circuit run with > n qubits?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction

I was reading the [Qiskit tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/fundamentals/4_quantum_circuit_properties.ipynb) on circuit properties and there is a section (Unitary Factors) which states that even though an example circuit is made of 12 qubits, it may not need 12 qubits to run.

The original circuit: [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/7b19bc411cf4787ae0f7dac322bd6aef306b8053/qiskit/fundamentals/images/depth_1.png)

[image]

The layers of the circuit: [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/7b19bc411cf4787ae0f7dac322bd6aef306b8053/qiskit/fundamentals/images/tensor_factors_1.png)

[image]

It is stated that: *We can see that at the end of the computation there are three independent sets of qubits. Thus, our 12 qubit computation is actual two two qubit calculations and a single eight qubit computation.*

I am struggling to understand where in this diagram it is illustrating that we only need two 2 qubit calculations and one 8 qubit calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the picture of layer #9. It tells you explicitly how to group the qubits. There's a pair (q0,q5), another pair (q3,q8) and the rest of the qubits (q1,q2,q4,q6,q7,q9,q10,11). To see the relevance, look back to the circuit. Start with qubits 0 and 5. You can see that there's a two-qubit gate between them, but there are no two-qubit gates going from one of those to any other qubit. So qubits 0 and 5 will be in a product state from everything else (assuming they start in a product state), and you can perform that part of the computation independently from everything else. The same is true for the qubit pair 3 and 8.